# standard function to count number of char in string C++

Tags: c++, string-length

is there a standard function like size() or length() to count the number of chars in a string. The following give 5 and 6 for the same word :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s="Ecole";
cout<<s.size()<<"\n";
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s="école";    
cout<<s.size()<<"\n";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Unicode!  You're counting UTF8 bytes; you need to use a wide string.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. I would like only count the number of chars in the string.For example the word should display 5 regardless its form( école or ecole).

Comment: Text is far too complicated to do that.  What about characters with multiple separate diacritics?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
wstring
```

Instead of:

```
string
```

Answer (score 0):

The string `école` is actually have 6 characters as the char `é` takes two bytes in memory.
The hax representation of `é` is `c3 a9`

The ASCII character set doesn't have a lot of "special" characters, the most exotic is probably ' (backquote). std::string can hold about 0.025% of all Unicode characters (usually, 8 bit char) hence if you want to store a string like `école` use `wstring` instead of `string`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there is no good answer.  Text is complicated.

First, you need to decide what "length" you're looking for to figure out what to call.

In your example, std::string::size() is providing the length in C chars (i.e. bytes).  As Vishnu pointed out, the length of the character "é" is 2 bytes, not 1.

On the other hand, if you switch to std::wstring::size() as suggested by Duncan, it will start measuring the size in UTF-16 code points.  In that case, the character "é" is 1 UTF-16 code point.

Switching to wstring might seem like the solution, but it depends on what you're doing.  For example, if you're trying to get the size of the string to allocate a buffer -- measured in bytes -- then std::string::size() might be correct, but std::wstring::size() would be wrong, because each UTF-16 code point takes 2 bytes to store.  (Technically,  std::wstring is storing wchar_t characters, and is not necessarily even in UTF-16, and each code point takes sizeof(wchar_t) bytes to store...so it doesn't really work in general, anyways.)

Even if you just want the "number of characters a person would see" (the number of glyphs), switching to wstring won't work for more complicated data.  For example, "é" (character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm'>U+00E9) is 1 UTF-16 code point but "é" can also be represented as "e" plus a combining acute accent (character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm'>U+0301).  You might need to read about Unicode normalization.  There are also situations where a single "character" takes 2 UTF-16 code points, called surrogate pairs -- although a lot of software safely ignores these.

Honestly, with Unicode you either have to accept the fact that you won't handle all the edge cases, or you have to give up on processing things one "character" at a time and instead do things one "word" (a string of code points separated by whitespace) to get things to work.  Then you would ask the library you're using -- for example, a drawing library -- how wide each "word" is and hope that they have correctly handled all of the accents, combining characters, surrogate pairs, etc.